# How to convert 2 numbers to 2 parts of a decimal number [C#]

Tags: c#, double, decimal, decimal-point

Im trying to convert 2 user inputed numbers (for example):

```
double number = 5;
double number2 = 23;
```

into **this**:

```
decimalnumber = 5.23;
```

Comment: What happens if `number2` is `23.45`? It's a `double`, not an `int`...

Comment: They should be integers for this to make any sense, as suggested by @dasblinkenlight

Comment: How would you represent 5.01 in this scheme?

Comment: @JonSkeet he didn't say that he intended to represent all floating point numbers :)

Comment: @NiVeR: Indeed, but it does highlight the oddity of the plan.

Comment: user can not input a number with a decimal point. That's exactly what i want frankly, to give him the ability to input these types of numbers. I'm making something sort of like a calculator in unity. I want the user to press the decimal point and after that be able to press numbers to represent the right part of a decimal.  ie ( 4,xx)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you should be storing these in two different numbers. What would you expect to happen if the user pressed "4.01" vs "4.1"?

Comment: To let user input some decimal you can just type:

    var number = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: it's an object oriented calculator... user has to physically press on the numbers/operations to make things work. So when he presses a number it gets stored. If he decides he wants it to have a decimal (example: he presses 4 and he wants it to be 4.65) he should have tha ability (after pressing on the "comma"(decimal-point) object to press numbers to represent the second part of the decimal number he wants to create.

This is a project been made on Unity btw. Im sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your **actual** problem about *physical calculator* - do not store it as numeric at all! Just use it like this:

```
var userInput = new StringBuilder();
....
userInput.Append(getUserNextChar());
....
```

Then just parse this input when it is actually needed as numeric:

```
decimal numeric;
if(!decimal.TryParse(userInput.ToString(), out numeric))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid user input!");
}
//use your 'numeric' here
```

Comment: Didn't think about solving it this way(using string). Makes sense, i'll give it a try. Thank you.